# Get nearby locations using google places api in php/Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var image_src = "images/";
  var map;
  var infowindow;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var PlaceArray = ["restaurant", "cafe", "bar", "grocery_or_supermarket", "parks", "school", "shopping_mall", "movie_theater", "bank", "university"];
  var PlaceCounter = 0;

  function initialize() {
    "use strict";
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(40.5456, -74.4608);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMapNearestPlaces'), {
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 14,
      icon: 'images/map_marker.png',
      scrollwheel: false,
      rankby: 'distance',
      styles: [{
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#00c775"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "gamma": 0.01
        }, {
          "lightness": 20
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": -31
        }, {
          "lightness": -33
        }, {
          "weight": 2
        }, {
          "gamma": 0.8
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "on"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "simplified"
        }, {
          "color": "#ffffff"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "lightness": 30
        }, {
          "saturation": 30
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": 20
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "lightness": 20
        }, {
          "saturation": -20
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "lightness": 10
        }, {
          "saturation": -30
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "saturation": 25
        }, {
          "lightness": 25
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
          "lightness": "0"
        }, {
          "visibility": "on"
        }, {
          "color": "#00c775"
        }, {
          "gamma": "1"
        }, {
          "weight": "1"
        }]
      }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }]
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pyrmont,
      icon: 'images/map_marker.png'
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    var request = {
      location: pyrmont,
      radius: 5000,
      types: ["restaurant", "cafe", "bar", "grocery_or_supermarket", "parks", "school", "shopping_mall", "movie_theater", "bank", "university"],
    };

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    "use strict";
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    "use strict";
    var place_icon;
    place_icon = "images/map-icons/" + place.types['0'] + ".png";

    var PlaceType = place.types['0'];

    if (jQuery.inArray(PlaceType, PlaceArray) == -1) {
      return;
    }

    PlaceArray = jQuery.grep(PlaceArray, function(value) {
      return value != PlaceType;
    });

    var Distance = distance(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng());

    function distance(latitude2, longitude2) {
      var lat1 = "40.5456";
      var lon1 = "-74.4608";
      var lat2 = latitude2;
      var lon2 = longitude2;

      var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180;
      var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180;
      var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1 / 180;
      var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2 / 180;
      var theta = lon1 - lon2;
      var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
      var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
      dist = Math.acos(dist);
      dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

      dist = dist * 1.609344;

      return Math.round(dist * 100) / 100;
    }

    if (PlaceType == "cafe") {
      PlaceType = "Cofee";
    }
    if (PlaceType == "grocery_or_supermarket") {
      PlaceType = "Groceries";
    }
    if (PlaceType == "shopping_mall") {
      PlaceType = "Shopping";
    }
    if (PlaceType == "movie_theater") {
      PlaceType = "Entertainment";
    }
    if (PlaceType == "bank") {
      PlaceType = "Errands";
    }

    jQuery("#near-by-place-detail").append("<ul><li class='left'><p><b>" + PlaceType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + PlaceType.substr(1) + "</b></p><span>" + place.name + "</span></li><li class='right'><label>" + Distance + " Km</label></li></ul>");

    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location,
      icon: place_icon,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    //now fit the map to the newly inclusive bounds
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    //(optional) restore the zoom level after the map is done scaling
    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
      map.setZoom(12);
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="near_by_places">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Near By Places</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="near-by-place-detail" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="near-by-place-map col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div id="googleMapNearestPlaces" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This code is not working and map is not loaded near by places. I have tried out above code but it is not loaded near by places. Any one know how to load near by places in wordpress. I have also used Google Api library.

Comment: Surprised that being in wordpress you don't get error `$ is undefined` ... or have you looked in console?

Comment: Yes, I have already checked in console .And wordpress is not giving me an error. I have also correct $ with jquery But map is not finding near by places. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I have already added script files but it's not working @dingo_d....

Comment: I've added it to your snippet, I know that you've added them on your page, but that's not helping with the snippet here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var image_src = "images/";
 var map;
 var infowindow;
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

 var PlaceArray = [ "restaurant", "cafe", "bar", "grocery_or_supermarket", "parks", "school", "shopping_mall", "movie_theater", "bank", "university"];
 var PlaceCounter = 0;

 function initialize() {
  "use strict";
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(40.5456, -74.4608);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMapNearestPlaces'), {
   center: pyrmont,
   zoom: 14,
   icon:'images/map_marker.png',
   scrollwheel: false,
   rankby: 'distance',
   styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#00c775"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"gamma":0.01},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"saturation":-31},{"lightness":-33},{"weight":2},{"gamma":0.8}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":30},{"saturation":30}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":20}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":20},{"saturation":-20}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":10},{"saturation":-30}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"saturation":25},{"lightness":25}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":"0"},{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#00c775"},{"gamma":"1"},{"weight":"1"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]}]  
  });

  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:pyrmont,icon:'images/map_marker.png'});
  marker.setMap(map);
  var request = {
   location: pyrmont,
   radius: 5000,
   types: [ "restaurant", "cafe", "bar", "grocery_or_supermarket", "parks", "school", "shopping_mall", "movie_theater", "bank", "university"],
  };

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
 }

 function callback(results, status) {
  "use strict";
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
   for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    createMarker(results[i]);
   }
  }
 }

 function createMarker(place) {
  "use strict";
  var place_icon;
  place_icon =  "images/map-icons/" + place.types['0'] + ".png";
  
  var PlaceType = place.types['0'];

  if( jQuery.inArray( PlaceType, PlaceArray ) == -1 ){
   return;
  }
  
  PlaceArray = jQuery.grep(PlaceArray, function(value) {
    return value != PlaceType;
  });

  var Distance = distance(place.geometry.location.lat(),place.geometry.location.lng());

  function distance(latitude2, longitude2) {
   var lat1 = "40.5456";
   var lon1 = "-74.4608";
   var lat2 = latitude2;
   var lon2 = longitude2;
   
   var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
   var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
   var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180;
   var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180;
   var theta = lon1-lon2;
   var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
   var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
   dist = Math.acos(dist);
   dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
   dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

   dist = dist * 1.609344;
   
   return Math.round( dist * 100 )/100;
  }
   
  if( PlaceType == "cafe"){
   PlaceType = "Cofee";
  }
  if( PlaceType == "grocery_or_supermarket"){
   PlaceType = "Groceries";
  }
  if( PlaceType == "shopping_mall"){
   PlaceType = "Shopping";
  }
  if( PlaceType == "movie_theater"){
   PlaceType = "Entertainment";
  }
  if( PlaceType == "bank"){
   PlaceType = "Errands";
  }

  jQuery("#near-by-place-detail").append("<ul><li class='left'><p><b>"+PlaceType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + PlaceType.substr(1)+"</b></p><span>"+place.name+"</span></li><li class='right'><label>"+Distance+" Km</label></li></ul>");

  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   position: place.geometry.location,
   icon:place_icon,
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.setContent(place.name);
   infowindow.open(map, this);
  });

  bounds.extend(marker.position);

  //now fit the map to the newly inclusive bounds
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  //(optional) restore the zoom level after the map is done scaling
  var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
      map.setZoom(12);
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
  });

 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<section class="near_by_places">
   <div class="container">
    <h2>Near By Places</h2>
    <div class="row">
     <div id="near-by-place-detail" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
     <div class="near-by-place-map col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
      <div id="googleMapNearestPlaces" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you add explanation what did you change so that others know what to look for if they have the same issue?

Comment: I have only add the two scripts..one is for the jquery and the other one is for the google map..